# How would I make a div automatically scroll to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chat

I want my div to automatically stay at the bottom when a paragraph is added, how would I do this? This is my code:

http://pastebin.com/wespDUXp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/tMnvJ/

Just put that JavaScript code in a function and call it by whatever process adds your content.  Something like this...

```
function addParagraph()
{
    //do you add paragraph stuff...
    //then call this line to scroll to the bottom of your div
    document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollTop = document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollHeight;
}
```

Hope that helps.